# Different ViewController if different selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

My code is

```
@IBAction func pressedButton(_ sender: Any) {  
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        if mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
```

Here I need if I selected Segment #0 on **ViewControllerA** (and press my button) then go to **ViewControllerB**, if Segment #1 then **ViewControllerC**, if Segment #2 then **ViewControllerD**.
Is it possible?

Comment: yes. It's possible. you have write right condition. Just push view controller in that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First wire a segue for each viewController.  <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the viewController icon at the top of `ViewControllerA` to another `ViewController` and select the segue type.

   [image: wiring the segue]
2. Click on the segue arrow between the viewControllers, and set its **identifier** in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for each `ViewControllerB`, `ViewControllerC` and `ViewControllerD` giving their segues unique id's such as `"segueToB"`, `"segueToC"` and `"segueToD"`.
4. In your button code, do the following:

   ```
   let idx = mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex
   let segueID = ["segueToB", "segueToC", "segueToD"][idx]
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueID, sender: self)
   ```

---

Demo of connecting two segues:

[image: wiring two segues]

Comment: Thank you deeply! But maybe I'm silly for that because I'm a girl. I set id for segue for ViewControllerB [like that](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f47ckfx3qj8na37/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202018-05-14%20%D0%B2%2021.02.35.png?dl=0). But when I drag from the ViewControllerA to ViewControllerC then arrow between ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB disappeared.

Comment: I just tried it and it works.  Make sure you are control-dragging from the viewController icon (left most icon at the top) to the new viewController.  You can wire up as many as you like that way.

Comment: that so sweet that you added GIF! my mistake was I tried connect Button (not ViewController icon). Now is ok, but my app is crushing right after run. If **AppDelegate.swift** `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate` __Thread 1: signal SIGABRT__ I even created new app. Put there only that code. But anyway. [My ViewController.swift code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg2nqs5rm0c2efp/2018-05-14-22.46.59.png) I connected to [both of them](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4w5bmc2s612x5f/2018-05-14%20%D0%B2%2022.48.17.png)

Comment: To find out where your app is crashing, add an exceptions breakpoint. On the left side of Xcode, click on the Breakpoint navigator icon (hover over them to find their names).  Then click on `+` in the lower bottom left and choose `Exception Breakpoint...` from the popup.

Comment: It looks like your segementedControl outlet isn't connected to the segmented control.  Drag from the circle next to it in the code to the segmentedControl in the storyboard to connect.  You might have to open the Assist Editor in order to do that (click on the two overlapping circles icon in upper right of Xcode to *Show the Assistant Editor*.

Comment: Sorry. We have different time. Yesss! It works! Thank you dear

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set id for them in IB and push if you use `UINavigationController` or present

```
if mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

     let so = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AID")

     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(so!, animated: true)
}
else  if mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

    let so = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BID")

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(so!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. No need "else" because I have few Segments. It's didnt work anyway because impossible connect ViewControllerA with more than 1 another ViewController

Comment: @LauraManukyan it's possible , emebd VC A inside a navigationController and set ids for any VC you want to present , you can infinitely connect vcs to a VC

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
     {

       let lvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cellVC") as! YourViewController1
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lvc!, animated: true)
     }

   else 
     {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cellVC1") as! YourViewController2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
     }
```

ObjC:

```
 if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
 {
  viewcontroller1 *yourView1=[[viewcontroller alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourView1 animated:YES];
 }
 else 
 {
  viewcontroller2 *yourView2=[[viewcontroller2 alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourView2 animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create enum for generic solution instead of using if else condition.

Create enum of your ViewController like this,

```
enum CurrentViewController : Int {
    case ViewControllerB
    case ViewControllerC
    case ViewControllerD

    var description : String {
        switch self {
            case .ViewControllerB: return "ViewControllerB"
            case .ViewControllerC: return "ViewControllerC"
            case .ViewControllerD: return "ViewControllerD"
        }
    }
}
```

Now go to appropriate controller, you can do this,

```
let currentViewController = CurrentViewController(rawValue: mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: (currentViewController?.description)!)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
```

Above is generic solution for all. Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible** ,Simply set the id of ViewController from StoryBoard

```
if mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

 let vcB = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCB")
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)

}else  if mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

let vcC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCB")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcC, animated: true)

}else  if mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

let vcD = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCD")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcD, animated: true)

}
```