# Calculated Values from VCA.swift to VCB.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know, on YouTube a lot of videos about how to Passing Data Between View Controllers [like that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2aN0mMMegU). But that is not what I need. I'm new on this website and in Xcode. I didn't find answer on my question here.
My App move from VCA to VCB with a segue.
I need pass Calculated Value from **ViewControllerA.swift** to **ViewControllerB.swift**
Example of my code in **ViewControllerA.swift**

```
let weight = Double(textField.text!)
let calculatedValueA = weight! * 2
let calculatedValueB = weight! * 3
let calculatedValueC = weight! * 4
```

In **ViewControllerB.swift** in **override func viewDidLoad()** will see results like that I guess

```
calValueA.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValueA)
calValueB.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValueB)
calValueC.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValueC)
```

Comment: How is your app constructed?  What is the relationship of VCA and VCB?  Are they elements of a tab bar controller?  Does the app move from VCA to VCB with a segue?

Comment: Hello! This is the same app [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328507/different-viewcontroller-if-different-selectedsegmentindex/)

Comment: Do you need I show screens or parts of code?

Comment: Just update your question to describe how you move from VCA to VCB.  Saying, I'm moving with a segue would be enough.

Comment: @vacawama done.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/1630618

Comment: It's not what I want. I said it in description. Even put link to video on YouTube

Comment: send only textField.text is definitely not what I need because my calculated value depends of UISegmentedControl and user check it on the VCA, not VCB

Comment: In `prepare(for:sender:)` assign `calculatedValueA`, `calcualtedValueB` and `calculatedValueC` to similarly named properties in VCB.

Comment: there just info from textField.text. In my VCA all calculated values inside of UIButton **@IBAction func acceptButton(_ sender: Any) {** Or I am too silly for that :)

Comment: It's fine to calculate the values in the UIButton @IBAction, but store them in properties of the VCA instead of variables local to the button code, and then you'll be able to access them and pass them on in `prepare(for:sender:)`.

Comment: I got just empty in VCB

Comment: When I put **func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {** and **secondViewController.calculatedValue = calculatedValue**  in to my button (after **if mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {**) then I got **Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String'** even I have in VCB **var calculatedValue = ""** and **label.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValue)**

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you need to create properties in `ViewControllerB.swift`

```
var valueA: Double?
var valueB: Double?
var valueC: Double?
```

When you are navigating form VCA to VCB then you need to set these properties with respected values.

```
let vcb = VCA viewcontroller....
vcb.valueA = weight! * 2
vcb.valueB = weight! * 3
vcb.valueC = weight! * 4
self.navigationController.pushViewController...
```

> Note: It is not good practise to unwrap optional value forcefully, you can use if let or guard to save app from crashes.

You can use delegation or closure to pass data to back to calling object.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you can do this:

```
    class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    func sendValuesToB(){
        let viewControllerB = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
        //calculate values
        let weight = Double(textField.text!)
        let calculatedValueA = weight! * 2
        let calculatedValueB = weight! * 3
        let calculatedValueC = weight! * 4

        //set the value of view controller B
        viewControllerB.calculatedValueA = calculatedValueA
        viewControllerB.calculatedValueA = calculatedValueB
        viewControllerB.calculatedValueA = calculatedValueC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
    }
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var calValueA: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var calValueB: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var calValueC: UILabel!

    var calculatedValueA : Double!
    var calculatedValueB : Double!
    var calculatedValueC : Double!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        calValueA.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValueA)
        calValueB.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValueB)
        calValueC.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValueC)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I got that **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** in line `calValueA.text = String(format: "%4.0f", calculatedValueA)`

Comment: You should check all the @IBOutlet objects are connected?